# Understanding slow queries from mysqldumpslow

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, php

I'm maintaining a system which sporadically (no exact time) but only at night causes the entire server to crash for a few seconds and the users seeing "Error Connection Refused" until the system restores itself.

The application server is running PHP and PHP-FPM with Nginx.

I've enabled the slow log on the database server and `mysqldumpslow` gave me the following output.

```
Count: 302  Time=44.50s (13439s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), 4users@2hosts
  #

Count: 44  Time=64.65s (2844s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), 3users@2hosts
  COMMIT

Count: 19  Time=82.44s (1566s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=295151.3 (5607875), site-admin[site-admin]@7hosts
  SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `audits`
```

I have a few questions regarding this output and would appreciate if anyone could explain whether these queries could cause both the application and the database server to completely lock up for a few seconds.

1. Are these queries running slow because the query itself is badly written or is it waiting for another query to finish?
2. What are the `COMMIT`, `#` and `SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM 'audits'` queries that seem to be running there?
3. Regarding the last query, I read this comes from a `mysqldump` command that was run on the server. Could this have caused a build up that evertually led to the crashing of both database and application servers?

Comment: Use `mysqldumpslow -s t` so that you get the "worst" queries first.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `audits
```

looks like a query from `mysqldump`.  Increase the global timeout -- so that it won't crash.

Meanwhile, you may not have any complete dumps for the last few months.  Panic!

```
COMMIT
```

I annoying.  It says that (for some unspecified reason) transactions are slow to finish.  You can't do much other than stare at the code.  And look for other transactions that are interfering.

But... Also check the specific times for both those `SELECTs` and and the `COMMITs`.  If they are happening at the same time, then the back up is interfering with normal traffic.

There are several alternatives to `mysqldump`, but this is not the Question to present a tutorial on dumps.

Re your last question:

1. mysqldump is locking on to `audits` for long enough to read and dump the entire table.
2. Some app is trying to update that table; it hangs waiting for access.
3. Other apps (or other copies of the same app) come along and get caught in the traffic jam.
4. Eventually some limit is reached (max_connections, the webserver's number of child processes, or whatever) and *that* decides to fix itself by restarting.

If the tables are ENGINE = MyISAM, switch to InnoDB, which is much more forgiving about table access.